# How to show, that a potential has no local maxima between its isopotential lines

Tags: real-analysis

I have a potential field $\phi$, given by a charged surface $\Gamma$ in the domain $\Omega$ with the constraint, that the potential is constant at the surface. This means my potential function reads

$$
\phi(x) := \int_\Gamma \frac{\sigma(y)}{\|x-y\|} \text{dy}
$$

with the surface charge density $\sigma$, which is defined by the constraint that the potential is constant at $\Gamma$:

$$
\phi(x) = \phi(\hat{x}) \ \forall x, \hat{x} \in \Gamma
$$

Now I want to show that
$$
\phi(x) \le \phi(\hat{x}) \ \forall x \in \Omega, \tilde{x} \in \Gamma
$$

As $\phi(x)\equiv \text{const} \ \forall x \in \Gamma$ I know that $\Gamma$ is an isopotential surface of the potential field, which tells me that the gradient $\nabla \phi(x) \ \forall x \in \Gamma$ is orthogonal to $\Gamma$.

That the potential field decreases for potentials far from all charges is easy to see, but I do not see how to show that
$$\phi(\tilde{x}) = \phi(x+\alpha(\hat{x}-x)) < \phi(x)\ \forall \alpha \in(0,1), x, \hat{x} \in \Gamma, \tilde{x} \in \Omega\setminus \Gamma$$

I guess somehow there should be a contradiction that charges which create a potential $\phi(\tilde{x}) > \phi(x)$ cannot exist because then $\Gamma$ cannot have an isopotential, but I do not see how to prove that.

Comment: The restriction $\Omega$ seems not relevant to the definition of $\phi$; only the surface $\Gamma$ matters. So thinking $\phi$ as a function on $\mathbb{R}^3$, it is harmonic on $\tilde{\Omega} = \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \Gamma$ and vanishes at infinity. So assuming that $\Gamma$ is positively charged, the maximum of $\phi$ is achieved at $\partial \tilde{\Omega} = \Gamma$ by the maximum principle.

Comment: You're right, $\Omega$ does not matter. But i fail to see why $\phi$ is harmonic on $\tilde{\Omega}$. When I have a sphere surface as $\Gamma$ I would expect a local minimum at the sphere center and the maximum on $\Gamma$ while the function vanishes at infinity.

Comment: An intuitive reason is that $\phi$ is obtained by a "linear combination" of harmonic functions $x \mapsto \| x - y\|^{-1}$. Also, if $\Gamma$ is a closed surface so that it enclosed some finite volume $\mathcal{V}$, then by your assumption on the constant value of $\phi$ along $\Gamma = \partial\mathcal{V}$, the potential $\phi$ must be also constant in $\mathcal{V}$. (This is again a consequence of the maximum principle.)

Comment: Thank you. Do you want to make it an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I add the comments from @sangchul-lee as a self-answer here, as he did not make them into an answer up to now.

When having a charged surface $\Gamma$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$, the potential field $\phi$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \Gamma$. By the [maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle) it cannot have true local maxima.

When by definition of the problem all charges are located at $\Gamma$ and $\phi(x)=\phi(y)=\phi_\Gamma\ \forall x,y \in \Gamma$, the function $\phi$ assumes its global maximum at $\Gamma$ and vanishes at infinity.

The interior of any solid which is bounded by a subset of $\Gamma$ has constant potential $\phi_Gamma$, as $\phi$ has no local maxima or minima and the potential at the boundary is $\phi_\Gamma$

The domain $\Omega$ does not matter as the previous is true in all $\mathbb{R}^3$.